# Using RKManagedObjectRequestOperation with getObjectsAtPath

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am developing a todo list app using RestKit on iOS, i have added a fetch results block for deletion of orphaned objects from official class reference from this link (http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html)

Now the documentation says whenever any `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`s execute, the fetch result block will check for orphaned objects and delete the objects automatically that are not present on server.

I am using the following code to make request, but the problem is `getObjectsAtPath` creates `RKObjectRequestOperation` and I need `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` can any one guide me on what to do in this scenario?

With `RKObjectRequestOperation` the orphaned objects are not getting deleted if they no longer exist on server.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/lists"
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) ...
```

Mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *listEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
```

Response descriptor:

```
responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:listEntityMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/lists" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "list_id": "1",
        "listName": "List Name 1"
    },
    {
        "list_id": "2",
        "listName": "List Name 2"
    },
    {
        "list_id": "5",
        "listName": "List Name 3"
    },
    {
        "list_id": "7",
        "listName": "List Name 4"
    },
    {
        "list_id": "8",
        "listName": "List Name 5"
    },
    {
        "list_id": "11",
        "listName": "List Name 6"
    },
    {
        "list_id": "12",
        "listName": "List Name 7"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `RKObjectRequestOperation` instead of `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` then you are using the wrong mapping. The operation is chosen based on the mapping which matches the request URL path pattern being an object or entity mapping. In your case your mapping needs to be an [`RKEntityMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKEntityMapping.html) instance.

Comment: but getObjectsAtPath documentation says it will create a RKObjectRequestOperation

Comment: and i am using RKEnitityMapping as in the following line of code

RKEntityMapping *listEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

Comment: What is the request URL and the corresponding response descriptor which uses that mapping?

Comment: p.s. `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` is a subclass of `RKObjectRequestOperation`

Comment: responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:listEntityMapping                                                                                          method:RKRequestMethodGET                                                                                      pathPattern:@"/api/lists"                                                                                           keyPath:nil                                                                                      statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

Comment: the base url is my .com domain with on receiving request like www.mydomain.com/api/lists returns json formatted all list as shown below 

[{"list_id":"1","listName":"List Name 1"},{"list_id":"2","listName":"List Name 2"},{"list_id":"5","listName":"List Name 3"},{"list_id":"7","listName":"List Name 4"},{"list_id":"8","listName":"List Name 5"},{"list_id":"11","listName":"List Name 6"},{"list_id":"12","listName":"List Name 7"}]

Comment: That looks fine, so the problem could be with the fetch block. Show that. Have you added logging to check that it is accessed and matches the response?

Comment: i posted the block on another question link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232402/restkit-nsfetchrequest-block-for-deletion-of-orphaned-objects
because that code would not fit here, and posted more problem description there.

Comment: That's where the problem is. Everything here seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't configure your manager correctly to work with CoreData (and create `NSManagedObject`s instead of `NSObject`s). Make sure to set `managedObjectStore` on the manager you want to use to download CoreData backed objects.

http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#task_Configuring%20Core%20Data%20Integration

Comment: i used the example provide by RestKit website