# RestKit NSFetchRequest Block for deletion of orphaned objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, rest, restkit

I have a Rest api hosted over my .com domain which on receiving request like this www.mydomain.com/api/lists will return the json formatted data as shown below

```
[
    {"list_id":"1","listName":"List Name 1"},
    {"list_id":"2","listName":"List Name 2"},
    {"list_id":"5","listName":"List Name 3"},
    {"list_id":"7","listName":"List Name 4"},
    {"list_id":"8","listName":"List Name 5"},
    {"list_id":"11","listName":"List Name 6"},
    {"list_id":"12","listName":"List Name 7"}
]
```

now i am adding a NSFetchRequest Block in my RKObjectManger to check for orphaned objects using this code

```
[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
        RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/api/lists"];

        NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
        BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO     parsedArguments:&argsDict];
        NSString *listID;
        if (match)
        {
            listID = [argsDict objectForKey:@"list_id"];
            NSLog(@"The listID is %@",listID);
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"List"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
            fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listID = %@", @([listID integerValue])]; 
            return fetchRequest;
        }

        return nil;
    }];
```

but my `listID = [argsDict objectForKey:@"list_id"];` returns nil, despite the fact the returned json from web has "list_id" in it. Please guide me what is going wrong here.

Comment: also my dictionary argsDict is empty. can any body tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: Your `json` response is an `Array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
listID = [argsDict objectForKey:@"list_id"];
NSLog(@"The listID is %@",listID);
```

because there is no `list_id` parameter in the path pattern `/api/lists`. So, if this data is missing, your predicate will always be checking for the wrong `listID`.

But, you don't need any of that. Assuming that the request returns all of the objects from the server - the only time you should be using fetch blocks - then you don't need a predicate. Just create a fetch request for the entity and return it without any predicate.

Comment: $10,000 - nice! Though I do usually settle for just ticking the answer as correct ;-)

Comment: @Wain are Fetch Request Blocks only executed for GET requests?  What if I have POST or DELETE actions to the same URL (which is common for REST APIs)?

Comment: @MattBaker, yes, only for GET requests. The assumption is that PUT / POST is creating / updating so the response should only contain that object, not a larger set where purging makes sense

Comment: @Wain That's what I would expect but the documentation didn't explicitly say that.  Thanks!